# Set class/prototype variable from jQuery function

Tags: jquery, variables, closures, this, prototype

Can somebody help me to understand how in this situation I can push values from $.each function into this.books array?

```
let Library = function ( name ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.books = Array();
};

Library.prototype.addBook = function ( book ) {
    if( Array.isArray( book ) ) {
        $.each(book, function() {
            console.log($(this));
            this.books.push($(this));
        });
    } else if ( typeof book === 'object' ) {
        this.books.push( book );
    }
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` is a jQuery function that calls the enclosed function for every element in the passed array. Inside the enclosed function, `this` becomes a reference to the element, and is no longer a reference to the Library object.

So inside your enclosed function, `this.books` points to `book[index].books`, where `index` is the index of the element in the array.

You can fix this by setting an alternative reference to the Library object.

```
var lib = this;
$.each(book, function(){
    console.log($(this));
    lib.books.push($(this));
});
```

---

Or you could use a loop instead

```
for(var i = 0; i < book.length; i++)
{
    console.log(book[i]);
    this.books.push(book[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function using `function()` syntax creates a new scope inside the function. That way, when you access `this.books` you are attempting to get the `this.books` from inside the `$.each` which hasn't been defined yet.

To solve this, use an inline function `() => {}`. Inline functions don't redefine scope and so you can safely access `this.books`.

If you are running on an older version of JavaScript and cannot use an inline function, then the solution is to put `.bind(this)` at the end of your function definition inside the `$.each` statement.